# How to link toggle to a class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to connect a toggle switch to the class

```
.wrapper.open {
transform: translateX(-20%);
}
```

using some jquery as well. Basically once the toggle

`<input id ="toggle-menu" type="checkbox">
     <label for="toggle-menu" class="wrapper.open">Menu on</label>`

is switched on the animation starts and moves the whole website left to show the menu switches.

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="overflow-wrapper">
     <div class="wrapper">
     <img id="logo" src="images/white-logo.png" />
     <header>

     <input id ="toggle-menu" type="checkbox">
     <label for="toggle-menu" class="wrapper.open">Menu on</label>



      <div class="nav-page">
        <div class="main-navigation">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

         </ul>

        </div>
       </div>

     </header>

    </div>
   </div>

</body>
```

### CSS

```
* {
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#logo {
width: 70px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 40px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;

}


header {
background-image: url(images/IMG_4849.JPG);
height: 570px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
}

li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 15px 20px;
display: block;
}

a {
cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
float: left;
margin: 30px -10px;
}

.nav-page {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #222;
transform: translateX(100%);
}

.wrapper {
transform: translateX(0);
transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}


.wrapper.open {
transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.overflow-wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

### Jquery

```
$(function(){


$('.toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('.wrapper').toggleClass('open');

});

});
```

Comment: `class="wrapper.open"` should be `class="wrapper open"` shouldn't it...

Comment: I just tried it but it doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find an element with a class of `toggle` but there is no such element in your HTML.

Your checkbox has an id of `toggle-menu` so:

```
$(function(){
  $('#toggle-menu').on('click', function(){
    $('.wrapper').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qe621mfc/)